# joining two dataframes with same columns but gives me ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, nsepy

I'm getting errors from my input function:

```
from nsepy import get_history

data1 = get_history(symbol='TATAMOTORS', start=date(2018,1,1),end=date(2018,6,7))

data2 = get_history(symbol='ALSEC', start=date(2018,1,1), end=date(2018,6,7))
data3=data1.join(data2)

print(data3)
```

This is the `ValueError` output that I receive:

```
data3=data1.join(data2)
ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: 
Index(['Symbol', 'Series', 'Prev Close', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 
'Last','Close', 'VWAP', 'Volume','Turnover', 'Trades', 
'Deliverable Volume','%Deliverble'],dtype='object')
```

Could anyone suggest why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 4):

`pd.DataFrame.join` is used for merging by index, it can be used to combine `DataFrames` given that they don't have any overlapping columns. What you are looking for is `merge` instead.

```
data3 = data1.merge(data2, how='outer')
```

**Notes**

There are couple of caveats, you are not importing `pandas`, `date` function is an import from `datetime.datetime` so this should be specified as well.

Comment: Consider accepting the answer if it met your question.